# Too many rows in chat app database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a laravel application and i want to build an instant chat Module for my application.

I have made a database structure by using the logic of Eloquent relationships (hasMany, BelongsTo).

Here is the structure:

[image: http://s17.postimg.org/3knkv55lr/IMG_1648.jpg]

The problem about it is that there is 1 row for every chat between every user.

Which means: (so bad) :(

for 50 users,
50•((50-1)/2) = 1225 rows

for 100 -> 4950

and for 250 users which is possible -> 31125 rows on channels table which will be queried in every message.

I need suggestions to make this smaler somehow

Thanks!

Comment: The quality of this question is quite low and you should reedit it (read in Help, FAQ about how to ask a good question). But, I must admit, that you made my day with a database structure written in pencil on piece of paper! :> I was expecting some computer graphic! :>

Comment: I can't see your tiny tiny tiny image, but how about if every Chatroom has many ChatMessages.
When a new message lands, you save it both to UserHistory (or whatever) and to your chatroom.
That way you can still look up old data if needed but only query the last 50 or so rows of your chatroom for relevant information.
And since everyone in the chatroom probably gets the same information anyway, you can also cache that query result until next incoming message.

Comment: Thanks, ill think about it. Also i dont have pc access which means: I will create a better schema with my pencil! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create my database like this

```
**Users**
user_id
username
etc



**Chats**
chat_id
chat_name
etc

**Messages**
message_id
message_user_id     ->foreighn key to users table field user_id
message_text
chat_id             ->foreighn key to chats field chat_id
```

**The amount of rows will be**

***1(unique chat) + amount of messages***

You dont have to save the users in the chat table, you can find them by looking in the messages table field chat_id

If you want to save the users which joined a chat (without posting a message) you could add a table

```
 **Chat_Users**
 chat_id            ->foreighn key to chats table field chat_id
 user_id            ->foreighn key to users table field user_id
```

**The amount of rows will be**

***1 (unique chat) + amount of messages + amount of users in chat***